# CSS設計で、アンダースコアではじまる乱数のようなclass名

Tags: css

CSS設計について質問です。
いくつかのサイトを調査したところ、「アンダースコアではじまる乱数のようなclass名」を見かけたのですが、こういったCSS設計は一般的なのでしょうか？

例：airbnb

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cssinjs

実際のページを確認していないですが、おそらくCSS in JSの類のことかなと思いました。
SPAやJSでレンダリングされる類のページでは一般的になってきているかもしれないですね。